# Independence of Lagrange function from time and position

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spacetime, symmetry, galilean-relativity

In Landau & Lifshitz "Mechanics", it is said that from the time/space homogeneity Lagrange function is independent from time/position. I always thought that homogeneity means that motion equations don't change with the time/space shift. So if i took the same initial conditions, i got the same trajectory. How to prove this statement?